# Is there a proof that this big-o statement wrong?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've been trying to find some examples that this is wrong because it is supposed to be wrong(?).

> if `g = O(f)` and `s = O(r)` then `g/s = O(f/r)`

Is there a counterexample that proves that this big-o division is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Take `g(n) = n^2, f(n)=n^3` and `s(n) = 1, r(n)=n^2`.

You can see that `g = O(f)` and `s = O(r)` but `n^2 = g/s ≠ O(f/r = n^3/n^2 = n)`

Answer (score 1):

Let `g = n^2`, `r = n^100`, `s = n` and `f = n^2`. Apparently the statement is not true: `g/s=n` and `f/r=1/n^98`. And `1/n` is  not in O(1/n^98).

One intuitive way to think of big-oh is "grows not faster than". However when you take the reciprocal, if "f grows no faster than g", then `1/f` will grow **no slower** than `1/g`.

A correct statement would be that if g=O(f) and s=O(r), then g/r=O(f/s). Note that in this case I swapped the pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This helped a lot

Comment: @JayKay9 I have added a little more information and I hope now it is even more helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

- g(n) = n²
- f(n) = n²
- s(n) = n
- r(n) = n²

Then:

- g ∈ Ο(n²) is true
- s ∈ Ο(n²) is true
- g/s ∈ Ο(n²/n²) = Ο(1) is **false**

Answer (score 1):

The idea is: if f is O(g) then f is bounded above by g, but not necessarily tightly bounded. I.e. if f is O(n) then it is also O(n^2), O(n^3), etc....

You can use this idea to find examples by making the denominator function large using a larger bound than necessary, thus making the fraction small.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O is just an upper bound.

Let `f=g=1` and let `s` grow slower than `r`. Then `1/s` grows faster than `1/r`.

Comment: Written informally on purpose, can be made rigorous. Also works with any `f=g`.